# Pinescript to fire an alert when the RSI crosses back below a value

Tags: pine-script

Im new to coding and i have found how to create a signal when the RSI goes overbought/oversold. I would like to have that alert actually fire when the RSI crosses back over the level.

For example: Overbought level is set at 80, Candle 1 is at 75, candle 2 goes to 85, candle 3 then drops back to 75. I want the signal to be generated on the close of candle 3 where it crosses back under (hope this makes sense).

```
//@version=4
study(title="RSI cross back", shorttitle="RSI Signal", overlay=true)
// Get user input
rsiSource = input(title="RSI Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
rsiLength = input(title="RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=10)
rsiOverbought = input(title="RSI Overbought Level", type=input.integer, defval=80)
rsiOversold = input(title="RSI Oversold Level", type=input.integer, defval=20)
// Get RSI value
rsiValue = rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)
RsiOB = rsiValue >= rsiOverbought
RsiOS = rsiValue <= rsiOversold
// Plot signals to chart
plotshape(RsiOB, title="Overbought", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown)
plotshape(RsiOS, title="Oversold", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `barstate.isconfirmed` to wait until the closing of the bar and the `crossover()` and `crossunder()` built in functions

```
crossunderOB = barstate.isconfirmed and crossunder(rsiValue, rsiOverbought)
crossoverOS = barstate.isconfirmed and crossover(rsiValue, rsiOversold)
```

Comment: Thank you. The closing of the bar piece was the next piece of the puzzle. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

"I want the signal to be generated on the close of candle 3 where it crosses back under"

just use something like

cbd=crossunder(rsiValue,75) 
cbu=crossover(rsiValue,25)